# Is it possible to sort the "input" and output of git-for-each-ref differently?

Tags: git, sorting

Git's `for-each-ref` command has a `--count` option and a `--sort` option that both appear to be very straightforward, but pose a problem when used together.

The sorting is used to determine how the count is applied, so if I sort by `committerdate` in reverse

```
git for-each-ref --count=30 --sort='-committerdate' refs/heads/ --format="%(refname:short)"
```

then I get the most recent commits at the top.  If I want to get the most recent commits at the bottom, the reversing the sort is not the solution because it will change the commits that appear in the list.

I want the ***last*** 30 commits (which requires a ***reverse-chronological*** sorting) but I want them displayed in ***chronological*** order, so the recent commits are at the bottom, and therefore onscreen even if the list has more lines than the screen has, and near to my current command prompt.

Is there any way of doing this with just Git (maybe some other command instead of `for-each-ref`?) and without piping it through another set of commands (which will reduce efficiency and introduce new problems, like extra work to avoid stripping colors--I'm actually using a much more complicated `format` string than the one shown above).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer:

> ... and without piping it through another set of commands (which will reduce efficiency and introduce new problems, like extra work to avoid stripping colors--I'm actually using a much more complicated format string than the one shown above).

The efficiency argument is valid, but... just do the extra work, using, e.g.:

```
git for-each-ref --format=... --sort=... ... | sort -k1 -s | tail +<count> | cut -f2-
```

where the `--format` puts the desired (non-colored) sort key for the `sort` command into field 1, as a decoration, which you then strip with `cut -f2-`.  Think of this as the usual decorate-sort-undecorate algorithm: the decoration is present in the initial input thanks to `--format`, and `sort -s` itself is stable on fields not used in the sorting.

(Apparently `sort -s` is not standard but is pretty widely supported.)

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to torek for the basic idea, but his solution needed a number of tweaks to work for me.  (I tried GNU versions in case differences were related to BSD versus GNU utilities, but that didn't fix anything.)  I can't be sure his won't work elsewhere, so rather than "correct" what's actually working, I'm adding this separately.

Here's what worked for me:

```
YELLOW_HEAD="%(if)%(HEAD)%(then)%(color:bold yellow)%(else)%(color:white)%(end)"
git for-each-ref --color=always --count=30 --sort='-committerdate' refs/heads/ --format="%(committerdate:short) ${YELLOW_HEAD}%(committerdate:short)  %(refname:short)" | sort -k1 -s | cut -f2- -d' '
```

I'm also adding my formatting, for sake of the answer being complete.

Differences with torek's answer:

- Initially I used `-` instead of `+` after `tail`
- Then I realized I didn't need tail, since I'm relying on `git-for-each-ref` to filter the count—and since I'm ***not*** relying on it for sorting, this is not a problem.
- I added in the formatting that messes up `sort`'s ability to sort properly
- I defined the delimiter for the `cut` command
- I'm telling `git-for-each-ref` to always show color, without which it turns color off before piping